# How to use cy.writeFile() in github actions

Tags: github-actions, cypress

I am new to cypress and I am using cy.writeFile('cypress/output/xyz.csv',`\n${headers}`,{ flag: 'a+'}) to store data, it is working fine locally when  I run through runner or terminal with headless, but when I run this test in github actions, test get passed but its not updating csv file,

can someone please guide what am I missing here and point me to any reference documents to look for solution or correct way to do it ?

Thanks

tried to search options from online and other source but no luck yet

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the file update? In the repo? That would require a push.

Comment: yes, I want to run this test in github actions on schedule base and collect data and store it to csv each time it runs ? if there are other ways to do it as well please guide me, thanks

Comment: But where do want the file to end up?

Comment: is it possible if it gets updated in repo and can be be pulled after run to locally ? or as artifacts or on gh pages ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write back artifacts to the repo with [stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action](https://github.com/stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action).

Add a new job or step after your call to Cypress run...

```js
name: Testing
on: [push]
jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
      - name: Commit xyz.csv
        uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
        with:
          commit_message: Updated xyz.csv
          branch: main
          file_pattern: xyz.csv
```

The full list of options are:

```js
- uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v5
  with:
    # Optional. Commit message for the created commit.
    # Defaults to "Apply automatic changes"
    commit_message: Automated Change

    # Optional. Local and remote branch name where commit is going to be pushed
    #  to. Defaults to the current branch.
    #  You might need to set `create_branch: true` if the branch does not exist.
    branch: feature-123

    # Optional. Options used by `git-commit`.
    # See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_options
    commit_options: '--no-verify --signoff'

    # Optional glob pattern of files which should be added to the commit
    # Defaults to all (.)
    # See the `pathspec`-documentation for git
    # - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt-ltpathspecgt82308203
    # - https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec
    file_pattern: '*.php src/*.js tests/*.js'

    # Optional. Local file path to the repository.
    # Defaults to the root of the repository.
    repository: .

    # Optional commit user and author settings
    commit_user_name: My GitHub Actions Bot # defaults to "github-actions[bot]"
    commit_user_email: my-github-actions-bot@example.org # defaults to "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
    commit_author: Author <actions@github.com> # defaults to "username <username@users.noreply.github.com>", where "username" belongs to the author of the commit that triggered the run

    # Optional. Tag name being created in the local repository and 
    # pushed to remote repository and defined branch.
    tagging_message: 'v1.0.0'

    # Optional. Option used by `git-status` to determine if the repository is 
    # dirty. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_options
    status_options: '--untracked-files=no'

    # Optional. Options used by `git-add`.
    # See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_options
    add_options: '-u'

    # Optional. Options used by `git-push`.
    # See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_options
    push_options: '--force'
    
    # Optional. Disable dirty check and always try to create a commit and push
    skip_dirty_check: true    
    
    # Optional. Skip internal call to `git fetch`
    skip_fetch: true    
    
    # Optional. Skip internal call to `git checkout`
    skip_checkout: true

    # Optional. Prevents the shell from expanding filenames. 
    # Details: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html
    disable_globbing: true

    # Optional. Create given branch name in local and remote repository.
    create_branch: true
```